# Django urls.py and views.py behaviour -

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I'm currently experimenting with Django and creating apps following the tutorials on the official website.

So my `urls.py` looks like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^/$','ulogin.views.index'), #why doesn't this work?
    (r'^ucode/$', 'ulogin.views.index'),
    (r'^ucode/(\d+)/$', 'ulogin.views.index'),
)
```

And my views.py looks like:

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the poll index.")

def redirect_to_index(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/ucode/')
```

When I run the server to check the test url, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/ucode` displays "Hello, world...etc" correctly, and works just fine. I've been messing with urls.py but I don't know how to get `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` to display ulogin.views.index.

Comment: what does your rool url conf look like? If my guess is right, `(r'^$','ulogin.views.index'),` should work

Comment: karthikr thank you so so so so so much

Comment: You are welcome. Also `(r'^ucode/(\d+)/$', 'ulogin.views.index')`  would raise errors for you.

Comment: Why would it raise errors? I was copying the code from the tutorial but I may have copied wrong (http://pystar.github.io/pystar/badges/badge_djangoapp.html#fix-the-hideous-default-representation)

Comment: Ill make it an answer explaining.

Comment: I appreciate it so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, for the pattern to match

```
(r'^/$','ulogin.views.index')
```

Should be

```
(r'^$','ulogin.views.index')
```

Also, trying to match the following URL would raise errors

```
(r'^ucode/(\d+)/$', 'ulogin.views.index'),
```

because there is no view method that takes `\d+` as a parameter.

The fix i recommend is:

```
(r'^ucode/(<?P<id>[\d]+)/$', 'ulogin.views.index'),
```

and then

```
def index(request, id=None):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the poll index.")
```

You can read more about [named URL groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) here

Comment: I think he's going through the django polls tutorial, he hasn't come across named arguments yet, I think.

Comment: I am going through the poll tutorial. But I appreciate the help greatly!

Answer (score 2):

It does not work because the root of a web-server when it comes to django urls is characterized by the empty string, like so -> `^$`. So, just change `^/$` to `^$`, and it will work.