# Django - urls.py and views.py and resolving error 404

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls

I'm fairly new to django. I completed the django project tutorial, and took away a good understanding of it, at least I thought I did. My understanding of how urls.py and views.py are related is urls.py points to the function of views.py and looks for a file to execute based on a page.

Here is my file structure:

[image: file structure of django application]

The root folder is right above the "friendfinder" folder called "ff"

The 404 error I have shows on all 3 static html pages: index, friends, and contacts.

Here is what my urls.py page looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from gather import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^interest/', views.InterestView.as_view(), name="interest"),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^friends/', views.friends, name="friend"),
    url(r'^contact/', views.contact, name="contact"),
]
```

This is my views.py page:

```
import json

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


from django.views import View

from gather.models import Interest


def index(request):
    all_interests = Interest.objects.all()
    return render(
        request,
    '   gather/index.html',
    {
        'stuff': 'TEST',
        'interests': all_interests
    }
)


def friends(request):
    return render(request, 'gather/friends.html')


def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'gather/contact.html')


class InterestView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            json_data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
            new_interest = Interest(
            name=json_data['name'],
            description=json_data['description'],
            approved=False
   )

        new_interest.save()
        return HttpResponse('ok')
    except ValueError:
        return HttpResponse('Fail', status=400)

def get(self, request):
    try:
        search = request.GET.get("search", None)
        interests = Interest.objects.filter(name__icontains=search)
        interest_json = []
        for interest in interests:
            interest_json.append({
                'name': interest.name,
                'description': interest.description
            })
        return JsonResponse({'search_result': interest_json})
    except ValueError:
        return HttpResponse('404 Page Not Found', status=400)
```

On the settings.py page I have under installed apps, I added the app named 'gather',  and

```
ROOT_URLCONF = friendfinder.urls
```

I also took a look at this page:[urls.py and views.py information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17814378/django-urls-py-and-views-py-behaviour)

I thought maybe my problem was a file structure issue.
Any pointers, hints, tips,and/or explanations of why the urls.py and views.py page are not matching each other's information would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Code for Friendfinder/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^', include('gather.urls', namespace='gather', app_name='gather'))
  ]
```

Comment: Presumably the urls you have shown here are the ones in gather/urls.py. Please show how these are being included into the main friendfinder/urls.py.

Comment: @DanielRoseman made edit with friendfinder/urls.py as requested